# If the current category ID exists in this array of IDs, then show something

Tags: category

I'm new to Magento, and I would like to know how to add a condition like my title above.

If the current category page is 3, or 4, or 5, or 6, then I need to show something.

Provided that `_category` is equal to `$this->getCurrentCategory`, all I can think of is this:

```
<?php if($_category->getId()==array(3,4,5,6): ?>
// Stuff to show if the current cat is 3 or 4 or 5 or 6
<?php else: ?>
//Stuff to show for other categories
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it doesn't work. I assume that my usage of array is wrong or I missed something. I hope I Magento/PHP expert can enlighten me. :D

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array)

Below condition shall work for you

```
<?php if(in_array($_category->getId(), array(3,4,5,6))): ?>
// Stuff to show if the current cat is 3 or 4 or 5 or 6
<?php else: ?>
//Stuff to show for other categories
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function for that.

```
$os = array(3,4,5,6);
if (in_array($_category->getId(), $os)) {
    echo "Got id";
}else {
echo "not";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(in_array($_category->getId(),array(3,4,5,6))){

}else{

}
```